# Count with how many spaces a string starts

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to know with how many spaces a string starts. Here are some examples:

```
string.1 <- "    starts with 4 spaces"
string.2 <- "  starts with only 2 spaces"
```

My attempt was the following but this leads to 1 in both cases and I understand why this is the case.

```
stringr::str_count(string.1, "^ ")
stringr::str_count(string.2, "^ ")
```

I'd prefer if there was a solution completely like this but with another regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^`  pattern matches a single space at the start of the string, that is why both test cases return `1`.

To match consecutive spaces at the start of the string, you may use

```
stringr::str_count(string.1, "\\G ")
```

Or, to count any whitespaces,

```
stringr::str_count(string.1, "\\G\\s")
```

See the [R demo](https://rextester.com/KHYE14397)

The `\G`  pattern matches a space at the start and each space after the successful match due to the [`\G` anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).

Another approach: count the length of `^\s+` matches (1 or more whitespace chars at the start of the string):

```
strings <- c("    starts with 4 spaces", "  starts with only 2 spaces")
matches <- regmatches(strings, regexpr("^\\s+", strings))
sapply(matches, nchar)
# =>    4    2
```

Comment: Wow, great, thank you so much! I haven't known this regex until now and I thought I know quite much

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - Great answer, do you this for Python as well?

Comment: @ManojK Python `re` does not support `\G`, but in Python, you may just use `len(text) - len(text.lstrip())`. You may try something like `len(re.search(r'^\s+', text).group())` but check if there is a match before checking group length. Note that with PyPi regex module, you may use `\G`, `print( len(regex.findall(r'\G\s', "    4 spaces")) )` [returns](https://rextester.com/AZGC40023) `4`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach might be to take the `nchar` of the input string, with all content from the first non whitespace character until the end stripped.

```
string.1 <- "    starts with 4 spaces"
nchar(sub("\\S.*$", "", string.1))
```

Comment: Thank you! Quite clever, but I prefer the solution of Wiktor, have a look at it :)